# How can I see which edge connects to which when UV mapping?

Tags: uv

In Maya, when UV mapping it will show the selected edge and the edge it connects to on the 3d model in the same colour so you know which edges can be welded together. How can I see this in blender?

[image: screenshot from Maya]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options in the UV editor, I guess you're looking for one of those:

- Keep UV and object mesh in sync.
- Automatically select the shared vertices.

You need to deactivate the first option to have access to the second. The first option keep a link between selected vertices in the 3D view mesh and the UV map selected vertices, second one only concerns the UV maps, but I maybe both will give what you want.

[image]

Comment: Not sure where Automatically select shared verticies is. Posted my answer as I do not have that option (could have been put elsewhere). Thanks

Comment: Where is that second icon? I can't see it there in 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have UV Sync selection

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, but moonboots replied first so will select his/her answer as correct.

Comment: moonboots is smarter than me so I completely agree :)